# google speech is not working in asterisk ivr

Tags: speech-recognition, asterisk, ivr, agi, google-speech-to-text-api

In asterisk i am using speech recognition from google cloud like this given below :

```
[inboundtest]
exten = 111,1,Answer()
   same=n,agi(googletts.agi,"Say something in English, when done press the pound key.",en)
   same=n(record),agi(speech-recog.agi,en-US)
   same=n,Verbose(1,Script returned: ${confidence} , ${utterance})
   same=n(success),GotoIf($["${confidence}" > "0.8"]?playback:retry)
   same=n(playback),agi(googletts.agi,"The text you just said was...",en)
   same=n,agi(googletts.agi,"${utterance}",en)
   same=n,goto(end)
   same=n(retry),agi(googletts.agi,"Can you please repeat more clearly?",en)
   same=n,goto(record)
   same=n(fail),agi(googletts.agi,"Failed to get speech data.",en)
   same=n(end),Hangup()
```

And from asterisk -rvvv i am getting the result utterance and confidence is comming -1 .
as i am following this example :

http://www.power3.ru/en/opyt/ip-telefoniya/nastroyka-golosovogo-menyu/

Answer (score -2):

Resolved some packages were not there :
yum install perl-LWP-Protocol-https perl-Crypt-SSLeay perl-JSON perl perl-libwww
working after installing this